# What do I need know (knowledge area) to track human joints in depth data (Kinect)

Tags: c#, kinect, openni, kinect-sdk

I am working on a project where I need to track leg joins on a sideway laid down person. After a week of research on the Kinect SDK 1.8, I couldn't find any article or documentation on how to do so.
Same for OpenNI, which doesn't have documentation on it, nor C#.

I am now thinking on using Kinect depth data to track leg joints by myself, but as I am blank I am wondering the knowledge areas I need to know to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Although I know nothing really about the kinect API I can google a few things...

So far it seems like its a map, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.coordinatemapper.aspx

It does look like it might store this data as a Int16. Although I can be wrong. If I was you I would consider Looking into the coordinate mapper more. I do think it might be difficult since the kinect api is intended to support upright gestures.

You might need to store and compare instances of the coordinates to properly design a application that can recognize a prone position.